# Como Editar os valores da tabela via JQUERY depois de recebelos de um web service

Tags: php, jquery, html, html5, json

Estou precisando criar funções para editar/alterar e excluir valores da tabela que chega via JSON de um web service, a parte do webservice para tratar o que vai ser enviado eu sei fazer, como faço isso do lado do JQUERY ?

Codigo html Tabela:

```
<table id="tabela-produtos" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">   
            <thead>                          
                  <tr>
                                      <th data-column-id="id_prod">Id</th>
                                      <th data-column-id="nome_prod_curto">Nome Curto</th>
                                      <th data-column-id="nome_prod_longo">Nome Longo</th>
                                      <th data-column-id="codigo_interno">Código Interno</th>
                                      <th data-column-id="cate">Categoria</th>
                                      <th data-column-id="preco">Preço</th>
                                      <th data-column-id="peso">Peso</th>
                                      <th data-column-id="largura_centimetro">Largura (cm)</th>
                                      <th data-column-id="altura_centimetro">Altura (cm)</th>
                                      <th data-column-id="quantidade_estoque">Quantidade Estoque</th>
                                      <th data-column-id="preco_promorcional">Preço Promorcional</th>
                                      <th data-column-id="foto_principal">Foto</th>
                                      <th data-column-id="visivel">Visivel</th>
                                      <th data-column-id="comprimento_centimetro">Comprimento (cm)</th>
                                    <th>&nbsp;</th>'
                    </tr>


          </thead>

      <tbody></tbody>

</table>
```

Reparem que eu busco os dados da tabela via JSON e faço um apend, preciso agora a parte de enviar via formulário a edição/ exclusão de um item, e de todos.
Codigo jquery que puxa os dados :

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/editarprod-todos',function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k, v){


    $('#tabela-produtos tbody').append("<tr><td id='id_prod' name='id_prod'>"+v.id_prod+"</td>"+
                                            "<td id='nome_prod_curto'>"+'<input type="text" name="nome_prod_curto" value='+v.nome_prod_curto+'></input>'+"</td>"+
                                            "<td id='nome_prod_longo'>"+'<input type="text" name="nome_prod_longo" value='+v.nome_prod_longo+'></input>'+"</td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="codigo_interno" class="table-editaprod-number2" value='+v.codigo_interno+'></input>'+"</td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="text" name="id_cat" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.id_cat+'></input>'+"</td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="preco" class="table-editaprod-number2" value='+v.preco+'></input>'+"</td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="peso" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.peso+'></input>'+"</td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="largura_centimetro" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.largura_centimetro+'></input>'+"</td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="altura_centimetro" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.altura_centimetro+'></input>'+"</td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="quantidade_estoque" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.quantidade_estoque+'></input>'+"</td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="number" name="preco_promorcional" class="table-editaprod-number2" value='+v.preco_promorcional+'></input>'+"</td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="file" name="foto_principal" value='+v.foto_principal+'></input>'+"</td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="text" name="visivel" value='+v.visivel+'></input>'+"</td>"+
                                            "<td>"+'<input type="text" name="comprimento_centimetro" class="table-editaprod-number" value='+v.comprimento_centimetro+'></input>'+"</td>"+
                      "<td>"+'<input type="button"  id="editarProdForm" value="Editar" name="editar"></input>'+"</td></tr>")


    });



    });

   });
```

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado no console?

Comment: Bom dia, Não tem erro , gostaria de saber como implementar isso.